# Is there a way to fix height of each row to a fixed of 10%?

Tags: html, css

I have the following css style which simply sets the  styling stuff for the HTML table.

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    

} 

body
{
    line-height: 1.6em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#hor-minimalist-a
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
}
#hor-minimalist-a th
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #039;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
}
#hor-minimalist-a td
{   
    color: #669;
    padding: 9px 8px 0px 8px;
}

#hor-minimalist-a tbody tr:hover td
{
    color: #009;
}
```

I have tried setting height property of **th** and also of **td** to 10%, but that doesnot work. If the number of rows get less, the rows automatically get larger instead of staying at the height of 10%.

The following HTML file is using the above mentioned CSS styling. Every thing seems to work fine except for the ROW length issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BOOKS</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("style.css");
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="hor-minimalist-a" summary="Employee Pay Sheet">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Employee</th>
            <th scope="col">Salary</th>
            <th scope="col">Bonus</th>
            <th scope="col">Supervisor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stephen C. Cox</td>
            <td>$300</td>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Josephin Tan</td>
            <td>$150</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Annie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joyce Ming</td>
            <td>$200</td>
            <td>$35</td>
            <td>Andy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>James A. Pentel</td>
            <td>$175</td>
            <td>$25</td>
            <td>Annie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stephen C. Cox</td>
            <td>$300</td>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Josephin Tan</td>
            <td>$150</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Annie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joyce Ming</td>
            <td>$200</td>
            <td>$35</td>
            <td>Andy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>James A. Pentel</td>
            <td>$175</td>
            <td>$25</td>
            <td>Annie</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I modify the CSS so that the height of ROWS stays fixed at 10% in any case.

Comment: You want each row to be `10%` the height of the parent? But you have 8 rows, how do expect `10% * 8` to be distributed among `100%`? What if the number of rows change? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Well I will implement pagination, so maximum of 10 rows at a time, and if there are 8 rows, I simply want 20% of the space to be empty and so on.

Comment: I believe the best way to do that, would be to have empty rows fill in the place. This way the UI is always setup to handle 10 rows at a time, but you can just fill in the data required for the rows that you need, rather than expecting the UI to adjust based on each case (especially if you are going to use percentages, what will happen if it's 7 rows? 6? you don't want to have to write a case for each one).

Comment: Can you try removing the `height:100%` of the `body`?

Comment: Agree with @FelixGuo. Don't overthink this, just leave the rows in and blank them out. [You can use `:empty` on `td` to remove borders / backgrounds](https://jsfiddle.net/g9hguf1a/) for example.

Comment: @Ofisora Yup that worked. :). Another way was to remove the height from the table. But that creepy. :/

Comment: Another solution is to wrap the table inside a div and set the height property of the div instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to set width or height as you mentioned both. But you could try `max-width: 10%;` or an absolute value, as I am not sure, what your aiming exactly. You also could try using `!important` like `width:10%!important;`

Maybe this helps. If not you could provide a picture with your aim so we can understand better.

Comment: Well I will implement pagination, so maximum of 10 rows at a time, and if there are 8 rows, I simply want 20% of the space to be empty and so on.
So I want maximum height of 10% per row.... But even ´max-height:10%´; is not working either.

Comment: Could you put your html and css into codepen?
I am not sure if you tried this already: <td height="10%"> put it directly in the html

Comment: its because our body was set to 100% width and height. I removed it and now it doesnt change height. You could set your tr height also with line-height if this helps. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvmYQq

Comment: Thanks :) . Another solution is to wrap the table inside a div and set the height property of the div instead. And let the height property of body be 100%. And simply do not mess with tables height property.